# RSPAN Monitor Session on Catalyst 2960X Issue

Tags: cisco-catalyst, netdata

I'm trying to replicate traffic in one catalyst 2960X port to feed it to a Linux VM to generate a graph of inbound/outbound traffic using Netdata. So I came up with the following RSPAN configuration (I'm just including the relevant RSPAM lines):

```
vlan 220
 name RMT_SPAN_1
 remote-span
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 description VLAN220 to vmnic3 Server 
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 220
 switchport mode trunk
!
monitor session 1 source interface Gi1/0/52 both
monitor session 1 destination remote vlan 220
```

Once everything is set up, I do receive the replicated traffic in the server, but instead of receive both Rx and Tx, I receive all as Rx traffic only.

After generating tons of traffic in both directions, this is what is displayed in the server interface:

```
ens192: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe26:39e0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:26:39:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4270105  bytes 5441999363 (5.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 821  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 5405 (5.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you see, Rx total traffic is 5.4G and Tx traffic is 5.4K. So, all traffic is arriving as Rx and is not being separated as Rx or Tx.

This issue is causing that the Netdata graph only displays Rx traffic even if it's TX. Indeed I also tried replicating only Tx traffic:

```
monitor session 1 source interface Gi1/0/52 Tx
monitor session 1 destination GigabitEthernet1/0/7
```

but the server received only Rx traffic in the interface.

Is this an expected outcome or is there something that I'm not understanding?

As a remark, I'm doing the same exercise with a Nexus 3k switch and in that case the Server displays both Rx and Tx traffic in the interfaceas it should.

Any help would be appreciated.

Switch: WS-C2960X-48TS-L

IOS: 15.0(2)EX4